# How to calculate mean over date range in two data frames

Tags: r, date, for-loop, subset

I'm using R, I have two data frames, one that contains columns for start date, end date, and station code while the other contains daily measures of salinity and station code. I would like to calculate the average salinity between the start and end date in the first data frame using the daily salinity measures in the second data frame.

Here is the first data frame:

```
> head(events)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  event_no duration date_start date_end   StationCode
     <dbl>    <dbl> <date>     <date>     <chr>      
1        1        4 2003-01-01 2003-01-04 niwtawq    
2        2        5 2003-01-06 2003-01-10 niwtawq    
3        3        7 2004-05-25 2004-05-31 niwtawq    
4        4        6 2004-10-31 2004-11-05 niwtawq    
5        5        7 2006-08-02 2006-08-08 niwtawq    
6        6        5 2007-08-07 2007-08-11 niwtawq
```

and here is the second:

```
> head(dat4)
   StationCode DateFormatted  Sal
1:     niwtawq    2003-01-01 1.58
2:     niwtawq    2003-01-02 1.19
3:     niwtawq    2003-01-03 1.31
4:     niwtawq    2003-01-04 1.56
5:     niwtawq    2003-01-05 2.10
6:     niwtawq    2003-01-06 1.33
7:     niwtawq    2003-01-07 1.68
8:     niwtawq    2003-01-08 1.83
9:     niwtawq    2003-01-09 1.77
10:     niwtawq    2003-01-10 1.56
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `tidyverse` could be to create a sequence between `date_start` and  `date_end`, join it with `dat4` using `"StationCode"`, `filter` the rows which are in range (i.e between start and end date), `group_by` `event`, `date_start`, `date_end` and  `StationCode` to calculate the `mean`.

```
library(tidyverse)

events %>%
  mutate(date = map2(date_start, date_end, seq, by = "day")) %>%
  unnest(date) %>%
  left_join(dat4, by = 'StationCode') %>%
  filter(DateFormatted >= date_start & DateFormatted <= date_end) %>%
  group_by(event_no, date_start, date_end, StationCode) %>%
  summarise(Sal = mean(Sal))

# event_no date_start date_end   StationCode   Sal
#     <int> <date>     <date>     <fct>       <dbl>
#1        1 2003-01-01 2003-01-04 niwtawq      1.41
#2        2 2003-01-06 2003-01-10 niwtawq      1.63
```

**data**

```
events <- structure(list(event_no = 1:6, duration = c(4L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 
5L), date_start = structure(c(12053, 12058, 12563, 12722, 13362, 
13732), class = "Date"), date_end = structure(c(12056, 12062, 
12569, 12727, 13368, 13736), class = "Date"), StationCode = 
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "niwtawq", class = "factor")), 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")

dat4 <- structure(list(StationCode = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "niwtawq", class = "factor"),
DateFormatted = structure(c(12053, 12054, 12055, 12056, 12057, 12058, 12059, 12060, 
12061, 12062), class = "Date"), Sal = c(1.58, 1.19, 1.31, 1.56, 2.1, 1.33, 
1.68, 1.83, 1.77, 1.56)), row.names = c("1:", "2:", "3:", "4:", 
"5:", "6:", "7:", "8:", "9:", "10:"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the dates are appropriately formatted then you can create a day sequence using the start and end dates and index the salinity values of your second data frame by matching those dates.

```
# Create ranges and name by station
ranges <- mapply(function(x, y, z)  seq.Date(y, z, 1), df1$StationCode,  df1$date_start, df1$date_end, USE.NAMES = TRUE)

# Match by date and station
df1$meansalinity <- mapply(function(a, b)
  mean(df2$Sal[df2$StationCode == b][match(a, df2$DateFormatted[df2$StationCode == b])]), ranges, names(ranges))

df1

  event_no duration date_start   date_end StationCode meansalinity
1        1        4 2003-01-01 2003-01-04     niwtawq        1.410
2        2        5 2003-01-06 2003-01-10     niwtawq        1.634
```